# Difference between "ModelAndView.addObject" and "Session.setAttribute" in spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

What's the difference between "ModelAndView.addObject" and "Session.setAttribute" in spring MVC?

Seems both them can share the Object and used in JSP .

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of differences, but you are asking from the perspective of the JSP page.

In that respect, ModelAndView.addObject will make the variable available to the **request** scope of the JSP, and Session.setAttribute will make the variable available to the **session** scope of the JSP.